# Finding an asymptotic distribution of dependent random variables

Tags: random-variables, asymptotics

I want to find the asymptotic distribution of $S_n = \sum_{i=1}^nX_i X_{i-1}$ where $X_i$ is a Bernoulli process with mean $p$.

If $S_n$ were independent it would satisfy the conditions of CLT and and $ \sqrt n(S_n/n - \mu)$ should converge to $N(0, \sigma^2$) in distribution.

Provided the above is correct it leaves to find the variance of $S_n$:

$var(S_n) = E[S_n^2] -  E[S_n]^2$

$E[S_n]^2 =\sum_{i=1}^nE[X_i] E[X_{i-1}] =np^2$

Now for $E[S_n^2]$

$E[S_n^2] = E[\sum_{i=1}^nX_i X_{i-1}\sum_{j=1}^nX_j X_{j-1}] = \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^nE[X_i X_{i-1}X_j X_{j-1}]$, these aren't always independent:

$E[S_n^2]= E[X_i X_{i-1}X_i X_{i-1}]=p^2$ for $i=j$ and $i-1 = j-1$

$E[S_n^2]=p^3$ for $i-1=j$ and $j-1 = j$

$E[S_n^2]=p^4$ otherwise (when they are independent)

I don't know how to proceed on calculation of variance.

Also I made the assumption that  $S_n$ is asymptotically normal based on independence. Would it still hold for dependent variables?